# Insert a related object by ID, using endpoints-proto-datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, endpoints-proto-datastore

I'm trying to insert a Category object, but I like to link a Category to a Store using the Store ID. The ID is by endpoints-proto-datastore.  How Can I do that?

Actually, to save a Category, the API require the Category name and the Store Key.

This is my api method:

```
@Category.method(user_required=True, 
                request_fields=('name'), 
                path='{store}/categories', 
                http_method='POST', 
                name='categories.insert')
def insertCategory(self, category):
    """
    Insert a category in a existing store.
    """
    category.put()
    return category
```

this is my Category model:

```
class Category(EndpointsModel):
    _message_fields_schema = ('id', 'name', 'store')
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    store = ndb.KeyProperty(Store)
```

and this is my Store model:

```
class Store(EndpointsModel):
    _message_fields_schema = ('id', 'name')
     name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have a Store entity that you want to include in your Category entity, be sure to use the Store key entity and not the id.  You can find the key entity in the datastore viewer (old version).

If you add the entityKey default property like so you can get the key in queries of your entity.

```
class Store(EndpointsModel):
    _message_fields_schema = ('id', 'entityKey', 'name')
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```